# Choosing a platform to start

Tags: kit, platform

I'd like to start with robotics, but unfortunately I know very little about HW engineering. Moreover I used to use such languages as Python, C# and Java, and do not have much experience in C. Still I want very much to be able to program a robot, and I have very big interest in Computer Vision and AI. Are there any platforms/kits that you can buy, and with little time spent you already can program them, preferably in high-order languages?

I'd prefer something wheeled (something flying would also be nice, but it may be too hard to be the case for a first robot), with a camera and some additional sensors. Would be also nice to have there something, that could help to avoid obstacles, like laser distance sensor or ultra-sonic sensor. Ideally I would like to build a robot that can navigate in the room without the help of operator. I'd like to look at SLAM some time in future, but for now I just need something to get familiar with the robotics.

Also it should probably be not very expensive, at least not before I will be very sure that I am ready to go deeper into robotics. Something for 300-500$ would be awesome.

Can somebody suggest kits/platforms/tutorials/any other info?

Comment: Questions about choosing how to spend your time (what book to read, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, and they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation and are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in [chat].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a life question.

Comment: I have created a room with the link to the question: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10566/help-for-starters

Comment: I'm using stack exchange chat first time, so any help is welcome either it is changing the topic or formatting

Comment: Given how little activity the main [chat] room has, you don't really need a separate chat room for this, since that will just keep you away from the few people who do frequent *Asimov's Corner*.

Comment: Ok, I was confused by the name of the room - I thought this is Asimov discussion only

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest trying [lego mindstorms](http://mindstorms.lego.com/%E2%80%8E). It removes a lot of the electronics, and mechanical barriers when starting to learn about robotics.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at mindstorms, they seem to be nice. Though would be nice to know more possible solutions to have to choose from